# Is it possible to make a self closing component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Just out of curiosity, I would like to know if there is any way to make a self closing component in Angular 2, just like the `<input>` tag. So that I can use it in my template like:

```
<div> <my-input> </div>`
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE 14.01.2023**

Yes.

As @Samathingamajig mention, Angular 15.1 (11.01.2023) introduction self-closing components, read him post for details.

Example of self-closing component:

```
// Previously:
<some-cmp></some-cmp>

// Now:
<some-cmp />
```

---

**OLD ANSWER 16.12.2016 (OUTDATED)**

<strike>For now, you can't create self-closing component.</strike>

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5563#issuecomment-161826319

Answer (score 6):

As of Angular v15.1, you can.

```html
<div> <my-input /> </div>
```

[GitHub release + changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/15.1.0)

[The pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/48535)

[Announcement on Twitter](https://twitter.com/angular/status/1613611774678384640?s=20)